# Node.js stream like functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a pretty simple app that allows users (friends and family, nothing public) to download videos from websites like YouTube. I'm now writing the module that wraps around the [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/) program.

**What I'm trying to do:** As soon as I request the module to start downloading a video, the module spawns a new process and initiates the download. The youtube-dl program will frequently return the download percentage along with some other details. I'm able to retrieve this data, but now I want to pass this data to the user that requested the download. Is there any way to do this in a stream-like way?

**Example of what I mean:**

```
var video = downloader( 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXX' );

// Will be called when the video starts downloading
video.on( 'start, function( info ) { ... } );

// Will be called when new data has been downloaded, contains the percentage etc.
video.on( 'update', function( info ) { ... } );
```

The part that download the video and retrieves the percentage has been mostly done, I just I don't know how to send data in a stream like way to the app that called the module to download a video.

Not sure if I explained it correctly and understandable, if you have any questions, please ask.

**EDIT:** Maybe I should use something like this?: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-nodes-event-module--net-35941

Comment: sounds like what you need is socket.io http://socket.io/ ,

Comment: I'm not talking about pushing data to a client, I'm purely talking about something like events from a module to the app that requested it.

Comment: do you want to pass the information to user who is downloading or to another module in your system?